# My defualt text is appear first then after a few second my replacement text appears

Tags: default

It looks awful.  Please have a look at absolute-websites.com/portfolio and you'll see what I mean.  What an I do to fix this please?

Comment: What do you mean? Which part in your site?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the Flash text at the top? Rasterize the text as JPG, GIF or PNG.